# Moving TikZ to github?

Tags: discussion, tex-sx-package, tikz

*Sorry, I don't know if this question should be asked here or on TeX.SX.*

> My question is : Are there some good reasons to not move projects with large supporting community (like TikZ) to github.com?

**Why I ask this question?**

I know that it is not up to the community to decide where some project should be hosted,
but maybe the community can influence the core team to do it.

And I believe that moving projects like TikZ to GitHub will benefit everyone.

**What are the pros to move to GitHub?**

1) Let's take one concrete example with [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223510/9335) and 
[this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223565/9335).

If TikZ was on GitHub this bug could be fixed in minutes in the following way :

- One person "forks" the TikZ repo, goes to file `tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex` (on github.com directly), adds `%` on line 339 and creates a "pull request" with a message describing this change. *(2 minutes max)*
- The core team of TikZ receives this "pull request", checks it and accepts it. *(2 minutes max)*
- And voilà, everybody can fix their personal copy of TikZ with a simple `git pull` from the TikZ folder on their computer. *(less than a minute)*

And this example is not an isolated case.

2) A lot of big opensource projects are moving from SVN (sourceforge) to Git (github), but I don't know a single one that is moving in the opposite direction. Probably there is a reason.

(The same way, nobody is moving from SVN to CVS.)

3) Big companies are moving their opensource projects from their own repos to GitHub (like [Google](http://www.engadget.com/2015/03/13/google-code-closing/) and [Microsoft](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/01/15/codeplex_repository_out_of_favour_as_microsoft_moves_major_projects_to_github/)) . Probably there is a reason.

4) GitHub has a solid business model that allows them to not have commercials on their site. This is not the case for SourceForge.

**What are the cons to move to GitHub?**

I can see only one : if the core team of TikZ is not used to using Git, it has to learn it. And Git has a not so short learning curve. But honestly, learning Git is far simpler than learning TikZ ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a TeX question nor one about TeX-sx: it's policy question for the developers of one package. As such, you will be best asking them directly.

Comment: On the question of fixing local code: that's what your local TeX tree is for :-) Fixing stuff in a development version doesn't affect most end users, remember (they need the developers to do a CTAN release, then for TL/MiKTeX to pick it up, then to update their TeX system.)

Comment: @JosephWright I know. But this is a question to the comunity and I don't know where else to ask it, may be TeX.SX is better place ?

Comment: No, that's rather my point: development is _not_ a question for the community, it's a question for the specific developers concerned.

Comment: It's mainly a question to the maintainers of TikZ, not the community as a whole.

Comment: @JosephWright I know how to fix a bug in my personal tree, but this is almost useless, because in this case my tex files can't be exchanged with colleges. And precisely because of this very long and complex "forkflow" that you describe, I suggest passing to something more "modern" ;)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. As I write in my question, I hope that the community can influence the maintainers of the project ;) And the community can have an opinion on something that they do not control !

Comment: @Kpym Yes it can: you send them a copy of the file. Moreover, what we really don't want is to go back to the pre-CTAN days where everyone had there own idea of what the correct version of a TeX file was.

Comment: @JosephWright Did you think that on other opensource projects everyone had there own idea of what the correct version is ? For this, there is an official repo with master branch inside !

Comment: Definitely wont disagree about a community having opinions. I'm still not sure about this being the right place though (and if at TeX.SX, the main site, not meta -- it's not a question about StackExchange). There is a mailing list at http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/mailman/?source=navbar, I would assume the maintainers read that, so that could be a first avenue of approach.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for the suggestion of the mailing list.

Comment: I'll open a chat room for this: quite discursive! http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29116/code-hosting-discussion

Comment: Did you read this [ticket](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/72/)?

Comment: @PaulGaborit no ... very interesting ! thanks.

Comment: @HenriMenke, the question seems to be open again, so go ahead and answer it, before it gets closed again ;)

Comment: You mean, _aside_ from all the good reasons not to adopt github, like [having an "F" from the FSF](https://www.gnu.org/software/repo-criteria-evaluation.html) or [all the reasons listed here](https://sanctum.geek.nz/why-not-github.html), like blocking users from particular countries or being Microsoft's [Trojan Horse](https://davelane.nz/microsoft-there-way-win-our-trust) to target open-source community, or [not being the best git-hosting solution](https://rocketgit.com/op/doc/compare)?

Answer (score 9):

PGF/Ti*k*Z is now available on GitHub.

> https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf

This commit officially changed all the links:
https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/94fb28ef7e6c3323f8b81117095b82f2f0fbabb8